# Uses of the 「-て」 conjugation of verbs

Tags: jlpt, て-form

I am trying to understand something from the N4 and N5 practice test book. I think the sentence has revealed a gap in my understanding of the use of 「-て」 verb conjugation.

The complete sentence is:

> きのうはうちに（  かえって  ）何をしましたか

(where the bracketed part was to be filled, and I have inserted the correct answer).

Word for word, I would translate this as:

- きのう - Yesterday
- うち - Home
- かえって - Returning (or something similar)
- 何 - What
- しました - Doing

But I am having trouble understanding the meaning as a whole; I think this is down the use of the 「-て」 verb. Some ideas for a rough translation are:

> Yesterday, I/you returned home by what method?
>
> Yesterday, I/you returned home and did what?
>
> Yesterday, what happened when returning home?

None of these really seem likely. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this an example sentence with solution? うち has no particle, are you sure you have the correct solution?

Comment: Sorry, yes I missed it off. I'll correct now.

Comment: Also, 何 is a question word, so I'd expect the question marker か at the end...

Comment: By the way, the ~て form has nothing to do with the しました at the end of the sentence, so you might to change your question title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ~て form can be used to chain sentences together. That is, any two sentences can be made into one by changing the verb of the first sentence into its ~て form. The result can be translated with the conjunction `and` and means that the first sentence happens and then the second.

In your case

> きのうはうちにかえりました。何をしましたか。
>   Yesterday you went home. What did you do?

becomes

> きのうはうちにかえって、何をしましたか。
>   Yesterday you went home and what did you do? *or better*
>   What did you do after going home yesterday?

Comment: For others looking for examples of the same thing, I have discovered this is introduced in chapter 16 of Minna no Nihongo 1.